# Tracing wallet IP address

Tags: privacy, anonymity, tor

I read about this privacy  attack to the BTC network : https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/193/how-do-i-see-the-ip-address-of-a-bitcoin-transaction

It is based on network observation from a malicious node.
Is that possible in the ETH network as well?

As far as i understand, when your node initiates a transaction, it sends a specific "create transaction" request to its peers,  which then know everything about that transaction  ( so input / output addresses too) as well as the IP of your node.

Comment: But, how an attacker can track this transaction to know the IP address for example ? as I know the IP address is encaplulated in the brodcasting message, only the nodes can read it, and there is no way to know the IP address from outside the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. An attack on Ethereum of this nature can be executed in the exact same way.